# Creating a multi use Timelock Contract

Tags: openzeppelin, timelock

I have created a basic Timelock contract. I'm going to have to lock and vest a bunch of different amounts of my ERC20. I was wondering if there was a way that this contract could hold different amounts, for different lengths in time and distribute to different wallets? I would need to bypass this constructor and create functions with the current constructor arguments. Is this possible ?

With gas fees as high as they are I'm trying to deploy just one timelock contract that I can interact with.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/TokenTimelock.sol";


contract TimeLockTest is TokenTimelock {
    IERC20 constant myToken = IERC20(0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4);
    address constant myWallet = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
    uint256 constant releasetime = 1654368599;

    constructor() TokenTimelock(myToken, myWallet, releasetime) {

    }

    function currentBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
    return myToken.balanceOf(address(this));

    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same necessity and I'm making something custom right now. I will deliver in a response soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach that I'm developing:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v4.5.0) (token/ERC20/utils/TokenTimelock.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";

/**
 * @dev A token holder contract that will allow a beneficiary to extract the
 * tokens after a given release time.
 *
 * Useful for simple vesting schedules like "advisors get all of their tokens
 * after 1 year" and release schedules are monthly.
 */
contract TokenMultiTimelock {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    // ERC20 basic token contract being held
    IERC20 public immutable token;

    // beneficiary of tokens after they are released
    address public immutable beneficiary;

    // timestamp when token release is enabled
    uint256[] public releaseTimes;
    
    // amount to release for each releaseTime
    uint256[] public releaseAmounts;

    uint256 public currentIndex;

    event Release(uint256 amount, address beneficiary, uint256 timestamp, uint256 releaseIndex);

    /**
     * @dev Deploys a timelock instance that is able to hold the token specified, and will only release it to
     * `_beneficiary` when {release} is invoked after `releaseTime_`. The release time is specified as a Unix timestamp
     * (in seconds).
     */
    constructor(
        IERC20 _token,
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256[] memory _releaseTimes,
        uint256[] memory _releaseAmounts
    ) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _releaseTimes.length; i++) {
            require(
                _releaseTimes[i] > block.timestamp,
                "release is before current time"
            );
        }
        token = _token;
        beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        releaseTimes = _releaseTimes;
        releaseAmounts = _releaseAmounts;
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers tokens held by the timelock to the beneficiary. Will only succeed if invoked after the release
     * time. Every release sets the index to the next release.
     */
    function release() external {
        require(
            currentIndex < releaseTimes.length, "no more schedules"
        );
        require(
            block.timestamp >= releaseTimes[currentIndex],
            "current time is before release"    
        );


        uint256 amount = releaseAmounts[currentIndex];

        token.safeTransfer(beneficiary, amount);
        emit Release(amount, beneficiary, block.timestamp, currentIndex);
        currentIndex += 1;
    
    }
}
```

It allows for setting multiple release dates. At each release, the `currentIndex` points to the next release date.

Ideally, it should check in constructor if the `releaseTimes` are ordered and they match the `_releaseAmounts` length.

Comment: Hi Pedro - If I'm right, for your contract I would only be able to set the same values each time. As an example, 1 million tokens distributed after a 6-month period and then the index resets?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can specify different values in different dates in the timelock aobve.

Comment: any wallet can trigger the release. Is there a way to add a requirement to the release function? only the Beneficiary can call release.